# Base RESTful controller conflicting with all other routes in Laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel, controller, routes

I have a `RESTful` controller for login purpose. But this RESTful controller is conflicting with all the other routes. I'm getting an exception `Controller method not found.` for all the other routes.

Here're the routes:

```
Route::controller('', 'LoginController');
Route::resource('receipe', 'ReceipeController');
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

It works fine if i shift `LoginController` route to bottom or if provide a base url to this route. But why all other routes stop working if `LoginController` is at top and with no base url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this controller route basically catches *every* request. Also note that the order in which you register the routes is the order in which Laravel goes through them to find a matching one. `Route::controller('')` gets checked first and matches everything so the other are never used. You have a few options to fix this:

1. Just change the order of your routes. (`Route::controller('')` at the very bottom)
2. Specify the explicit routes of `LoginController`. For example:

   `Route::get('', 'LoginController@index');`
   `Route::get('register', 'LoginController@register');`
   and so on..
3. Use a static URL segment instead of root (`''`). Obviously this will change your URLs a bit.

   `Route::controller('login', 'LoginController');`